# "DateTime.beginning_of_week => :monday" but "DateTime.current.wday == 0" is Sunday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

`DateTime.current.wday` starts counting the week from Sunday.

I want the weeks to be counted beginning with monday.

I don't get this discrepancy.

How would I get today's weekday in numeric representation?

Comment: Today is wednesday and it's returning 3, what's wrong?

Comment: @RSB it starts from 0, thus 3 is the 4th day of the week...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe traditionally weeks are considered to start with Sunday as the first day of the week. If you wanted to represent the week as starting with a different day, for example Monday, you could do something like

```
(DateTime.current.wday + 6) % 7
```

aside from that I believe there is a strftime to get what you are looking for but it will be returned as a string.

Comment: Well...
Genesis 2:2

Answer (score 6):

The `wday` method in Ruby is always going to give you the value 0 through 6, where 0 is Sunday because that is its definition.

If you want a weekday number in the range 1 through 7 (where 1 is Monday) use `strftime('%u')` instead.  Using `'%w'` will give you a range 0 through 6 (where 0 is Sunday).

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > Date.new(2014,5,4).strftime('%u')
 => "7" 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > Date.new(2014,5,4).strftime('%w')
 => "0" 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > Date.new(2014,5,4)
 => Sun, 04 May 2014
```

What you regard as the beginning of the week though varies according to where you are in the world.  Rails gives you a `Date.beginning_of_week=(week_start)` method to let you change this, but Monday is taken as the default.